# Issue Accessing the Web API hosted in a Web app from Another Web App when another web app

Tags: azure, authentication, token, azure-active-directory, access-token

We have two web application both secured by Azure AD. and share the login. Meaning If user is logged in to Web Application 1 then no need to login to Application 2. Works fine. 
Here is what the app does. 
Web Application 1: Host Some Web API that Web Application 2 access. 
Web Applicaiton 2: Access the Web Api of Application 1.

Here is the issue. 
User login to the application 1. and the token cache is created. User go to Application 2 and it automatically log the user in. Now, user perform the action which call the api of Web Application 1 and it uses the cached token (Web App 1 and 2 share the same cache token) and it fails.

It obvious that it fails as Web App 1 obtained the token for the audience (graph.windows.net) and Web App 2 is trying to access it to access Web App 1.

I'm not getting a good way out. If i change the login order Web App 2 and then Web App 1 then it will work, but I have the requirement to do it the other way. where User first come to Web App 1.

Looking forward for some help.

Comment: How many apps are in Azure AD? Two or one?

Comment: Two apps in Azure Ad. Web App 2 is given permission to access Web App 1 in Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are actually two apps in Azure AD, I would generally recommend them not to share a token cache.

The user will not have to log in twice, since they should be automatically signed in to the other app (due to Single Sign-On).
Depends on some parameters and the situation of course.

Both apps should then be able to acquire any tokens they need as normal.